# Code works sometimes, and sometimes it returns "list index out of range" instead

Tags: python

I'm getting this issue in quite a few different places throughout my code, but I'll only post the simplest code where I'm getting this issue so I can learn from it.

My code works sometimes, and other times it doesn't. When it doesn't work, I get `IndexError: list index out of range` returned. Its in a class called Students, data is referencing a .txt file that has 800 students in it (give or take).

```
def SearchStudent(self, data):
    
  students = []
  with open(data, "r") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
      datum = line.split()
      students.append(datum)
        
   searchFirstName = input('Enter students first name: ')

   for datum in students:
     if datum[1] == searchFirstName:
       print(datum)
```

Error seems to hit the `if datum[1] == searchFirstName:` part when it happens, but struggling to wrap my head around why it's happening.

Comment: It's because *datum* is a list with fewer than 2 elements

Comment: if `datum` is empty or contains only 1 element, there is no element at index 1 to get with `datum[1]`.

Comment: Have you ran debugger with your code with breakpoint on that line?

Comment: If `datum = line.split()` does not give you at least two elements because there is no whitespace in `line`, you can't access `datum[1]` because it doesn't exist.

Comment: have you checked if datafile have any content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revise like below to do a basic check:

```
for datum in students:      
    if len(datum) > 1 and datum[1] == searchFirstName:
        # note index[0] on the list would mean a list length of 1, so looking >1 to get a list containing at least an index[1]
        print(datum)
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be because the line in the datafile might be empty which is ultimately resulting in an error in the if condition that you have configured.

i.e
error in the following line

```
datum = line.split()
```

You can add another if condition before this if condition `if datum[1] == searchFirstName:` as `if len(datum) > 1:`

i.e

```
if len(datum) > 1:
   if datum[1] == searchFirstName:
```

Comment: Needs to be len() > 1 as your using the 2nd index of the list - [1] - not [0]